# How to represent request submission and approval data in Oracle using pivoting?

Tags: oracle, pivot, hierarchical

I have data set for request submission and its approval process history. I need to represent each request number with its submission sequence date and final approval and reject date. Like I have data set like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx0fy.png) attached image. and I want to display it as shown in below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn0Uc.png)

I tried pivoting but couldn't get it because pivot will work on only aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT
req_num,
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 AND action = "SUBMIT" THEN action_date END) AS "1st submission",
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 AND action = "SUBMIT" THEN action_date END) AS "2nd submission",
MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 AND action = "SUBMIT" THEN action_date END) AS "3rd submission",
-- Add more MAX(CASE WHEN rn = N THEN action_date END) for additional submissions
MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'APPROVAL' THEN action_date END) AS max_approval,
MAX(CASE WHEN action = 'REJECT' THEN action_date END) AS reject 
FROM
(
SELECT
    req_num,
    action_date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY req_num ORDER BY action_date) AS rn,
    action
FROM
    requests
) sub
GROUP BY req_num;
```

Comment: thanks for your help for the query. But actually its not fixed for 3 or more submission. May be its 1 only submit status or may be employee tries 15 times and having submit status with one request only. We don't know. only we can pick up max Approve or Reject. But Submission we need to do some dynamic. Hope I'm able to explain exact requirements